# How do you get the default binding mode of a dependency property?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, dependency-properties, binding-mode

I want to programmatically find out what the default binding mode of a property will be.

For example, if I check it against `TextBox.TextProperty` it should be `BindingMode.TwoWay`, but if it is `ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty` it should be `BindingMode.OneWay`.

I implemented a custom MarkupExtension and have gotten this far in my code so far:

```
public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider provider)
{
    var service = provider.GetService(typeof(IProvideValueTarget)) as IProvideValueTarget;

    if (service != null)
    {
        var target = service.TargetObject as DependencyObject;
        var property = service.TargetProperty as DependencyProperty;

        // Not sure what to do with the target and propery here...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`DependencyProperty.GetMetadata`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597486.aspx) on the `DependencyObject`. This will give you a `PropertyMetadata` value that will usually be an instance of `FrameworkPropertyMetadata`. Cast to that type if possible and check the value of [`BindsTwoWayByDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkpropertymetadata.bindstwowaybydefault.aspx).

For example:

```
var metadata = property.GetMetadata(target) as FrameworkPropertyMetadata;
if (metadata != null)
{
    var isTwoWay = metadata.BindsTwoWayByDefault;
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing that by this answer there is no way for a DependencyProperty to be set to `BindingMode.OneTime` by default? It's either TwoWay or not?

Comment: @michael: For framework-specific properties, yes. `OneTime` and `OneWayToSource` AFAIK exist only to better support data binding with plain .NET properties.